# How to dynamically add attributes to mulitple div with same class name using jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a "div" written in my html code like this

```
<div class="mydata">
</div>
```

and this is created dynamically when page renders so how many div with this same class name is going to be created is not fixed but using my code i can get the total no of div presented at a time after page load.

i stored that value in a variable "counter".

so for example at some time if their are 5 div with "mydata" class name then counter have 5 value

but now i want to add id attribute(Start from 1 upto counter value)   to each div.

ex: first div is look like this `<div class="mydata" id="1"></div>`

second one is like this `<div class="mydata" id="2"></div> and so on.`

so please tell me how can add this id attr to my div(as discribed other )using jquery ?

-Thanks

Comment: How do you generate the `<div class="mydata">`? I think it's much saner to add the `id` attribute upon create and increment it by 1 everytime you add a new one.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No need for the counter.

However you can't use only a number for the id attribute. It must start with a letter.

> ID and NAME tokens must begin with a letter ([A-Za-z]) and may be
>   followed by any number of letters, digits ([0-9]), hyphens ("-"),
>   underscores ("_"), colons (":"), and periods (".").

[**ID and NAME tokens**](http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/types.html#type-name)

---

Here is the jQuery code:

```
$('.mydata').each(function(i){
    $(this).attr('id', 'id_'+(i+1));
});
```

The IDs will be:

```
<div class="mydata" id="id_1"></div>
<div class="mydata" id="id_2"></div>
...
```

Comment: thanks it works :-) i will accept the answer asap it allowed by this website

Answer (score 3):

```
$('.mydata').each(function(index, element) {
    $(element).attr('id', 'id_' + (index + 1));
});
```

Comment: No need to wrap the `element` again, it is already a `jQuery` object. The way you have it would be like this `$($(this))`.

Comment: No, you get the dom element, not a jquery element.

Answer (score 0):

```
var i  = 1 ;

$('.mydata').each(function(){

$(this).attr('id',i);

i++;

});
```

Answer (score 0):

Also,

```
$('.mydata').attr('id', function (i, oldValue) {
    return 'id_' + i;
});
```

Nice and simple :)